# uitableview - data and if (!cell)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a big problem with an UITableView, I want to use a label inside the cell, so  I use this method for do it

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemCell";

// If the indexPath is less than the numberOfItemsToDisplay, configure and return a normal cell,
// otherwise, replace it with a button cell.

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
else {

}

if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    elemento = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *labelTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 220, 30)];
    labelTitle.text = [elemento objectForKey:@"Titolo"];
    labelTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    labelTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell addSubview:labelTitle];

} else {

    UILabel *labelTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 220, 30)];
    labelTitle.text = @"Read More";
    labelTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    labelTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell addSubview:labelTitle];

}


return cell;
```

}

in this way I can see all the data on my table, but the label are overlap, than I try to use this method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemCell";

// If the indexPath is less than the numberOfItemsToDisplay, configure and return a normal cell,
// otherwise, replace it with a button cell.

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        elemento = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UILabel *labelTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 220, 30)];
        labelTitle.text = [elemento objectForKey:@"Titolo"];
        labelTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        labelTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [cell addSubview:labelTitle];

    } else {

        UILabel *labelTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 220, 30)];
        labelTitle.text = @"Read More";
        labelTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        labelTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [cell addSubview:labelTitle];

    }

}
else {

}

return cell;
```

}

the label are OK but in this case I can see on my table only 5 data, and this 5 data are repeat for some time...

For example if in the first case on my table I can see: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...
in the second case I seee: 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,...

where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code

```
  for (UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews]) 
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

**before**

if (indexPath.section == 0) {

```
elemento = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *labelTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 220, 30)];
labelTitle.text = [elemento objectForKey:@"Titolo"];
labelTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
labelTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[cell addSubview:labelTitle];
```

Currently you add a label to the cell and the next time the cell is reused..the label is still there and you add a label on top of it.

Comment: yeah..one more thing you have to do is add the label as `[cell.contentView addSubview:labelTitle];` not as cell addSubvuew

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is specifying `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` as the cell style, which means each cell will a text label and detail text label available in its corresponding properties `textLabel`, and `detailTextLabel`. So there's no reason for you to allocate additional instances of `UILabel`. Instead, just populate the `text` properties of the existing labels. For example, you could rewrite your implementation like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellID = @"ItemCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellID];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = (indexPath.section == 0 ?
                           [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] :
                           @"ReadMore");    

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I need to add also a imageview on the left, and I can do it only adding label & imageview...I can do it with the accessory view but they are only on the right...

Comment: There'a already an image view on the left that you can access through the `imageView` property of your `UITableViewCell` instance.